# how do i refactor middlewares routes in express?

Tags: express, routes, refactoring

I have a question. Following this code:

```
const express = require('express');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const carsRouter = require('./routes/cars');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/cars', carsRouter);
//and other app use routes

module.exports = app;
```

the question is about app.use routes, imagine having 50, 100, 1000 of routes, it isnt a best practise to update app.js everytime! how to refactor it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible cases:

1. there are actually 50, 100, 1000 different functions (or routers) that corresponds that many routes. In this case, you need to organize them in some neat way. I suggest scanning folders and calling `app.use` them in a cycle.
2. there aren't so many different functions, but instead there are copy/paste code or maybe some few routes correspond to one function. This means you can either organize that functions in an array and then, make `app.use` inside of a loop. Or, maybe you can create generic muddleware that analyzes path and calls proper function to deal with the request:

```js
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      if (req.path.match(/.../)) {
        return ...
      }
      if (req.path.match(/.../)) {
        return ...
      }
    
      ...
    
      // if nothing matches, run the next middleware
      next();
    });
```